# How to get the count of number of records in structured streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a spark structured streaming, where I need to stop the streaming process once I have the correct records count.

So far I have a method to stop streaming at particular interval of no activity, how can I include a counter to get the count and close the stream?

```
 val resultStream=furtherFlattening
      .writeStream
      .format("console")
      .option("truncate","false")
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
      //. trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
      .start()

      .awaitTermination()


def stopStreamQuery(query: StreamingQuery, awaitTerminationTimeMs: Long,spark:SparkSession) {

  while (query.isActive) {
    val msg = query.status.message
    if (!query.status.isDataAvailable
      && !query.status.isTriggerActive
      && !msg.equals("Initializing sources")) {
      query.stop()
      spark.close()
    }
    query.awaitTermination(awaitTerminationTimeMs)
  }
}
```